# Skyline solver for AX=B where A is symmetric skyline matrix

Tags: linear-solver, fortran, data-storage

I am looking for a simple subroutine in Fortran 90 (GNU Compiler) to solve linear equation of the type $AX=B$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix stored in the form of symmetric skyline matrix.
I want a solution of this type:

```
X = skysolve(A,p,X,B,n)
A = {11,22,13,0,33,24,34,44,55,16,0,0,46,56,66}
```

where `p` is the index of diagonal elements `p = {1,2,5,8,9,15}`

It would be better if I could just have a simple subroutine kind of solution to this situation rather than a library.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Am I correct in assuming that you are re-asking [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21829) after having registered? If so, it might make sense to edit this question to include the additional information in the other question (and also describe what a "skyline matrix" is) and then delete the old question (if you can; otherwise flag for a moderator to delete it).

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am unable to delete that question and unless I remove that content, cannot duplicate it here

Comment: I've copied the content for you -- if that's not what you want, feel free to revert the edit (or make a comment). To edit your question yourself (to include the definition of a skyline matrix, for example ;)), you can use the grey `edit` link under the tags.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at the FEAPpv finite element code written by Robert
Taylor to accompany this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Finite-Element-Method-Fundamentals/dp/1856176339](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1856176339)

You can download the fortran source code from this page:

http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/projects/feap/feappv/

The code contains two subroutines, `datri` and `dasol` that perform the factorization and solution, respectively, of a matrix stored in skyline format; you first call `datri` to the factor the matrix and then call `dasol` to perform the forward and backward substitutions.

There are sufficiently detailed comments in both subroutines to be able to use them. Here is a simple example with five equations and a symmetric matrix (entries below the diagonal are not included):

```
      program test
C
C  Solve A*U = b      
C        [2   -2    0    0   -1]
C        [0    3   -2    0    0]
C  A =   [0    0    5   -3    0]
C        [0    0    0   10    4]
C        [0    0    0    0   10] 
C
C The solution, U, is: 636.,619.,292.,74.,34.
C
        parameter (neqs = 5)
        real*8 au(7), ad(neqs), b(neqs), energy
        integer jp(neqs)
        data au/-2.,-2.,-3.,-1.,0.,0.,4./
        data ad/2.,3.,5.,10.,10./
        data b/0.,1.,0.,0.,0./
        data jp/0,1,2,3,7/
        call datri(0, au, ad, jp, neqs, neqs)
        call dasol(0, au, ad, b, jp, neqs, neqs, energy)
        write(6,*) 'solution', (b(i), i=1,neqs)
      end
```

Comment: I appreciate these subroutines, which are simpler in a way but there are many dependent subroutines and headers. I have tried adding them all and when I compiled I get a few warnings (Warning 3 Incorrect level in dot) and the result ends up with 'NaN'  for all. I am using GNU Fortran using Codeblocks.

Comment: I tested with gfortran 4.8.3 and get no warning messages. I added the exact solution to the comments in the example code above, by the way.